# A more pythonic way to do permutations?

Tags: python, permutation, combinatorics

I am trying to build a back testing algorithm to determine combinatorically what kind of cash position a portfolio should have based on how much the market has dropped from all time high. Trying to see if there is a way to save on time, because this will take a few days to run at this setup. I ran this for a few hours and it didn't make it far down the combinatorics path haha

This is going to be updated on a [public github](https://github.com/Jakub-MFP/My_FIRE_Project/blob/master/portfolio_management/cashposition_backtest.ipynb)

A simplified version of what I am trying to do

```
    if (current_market_status > 0):  #greater than 0
        current_cash_required_equity = 0.3
    elif (current_market_status > -0.05): #less than 5%
        current_cash_required_equity = 0.25
    elif (current_market_status > -0.10): #less than 10%
        current_cash_required_equity = 0.20 
    elif (current_market_status > -0.15): #less than 15%
        current_cash_required_equity = 0.15
    elif (current_market_status > -0.20): #less than 20%
        current_cash_required_equity = 0.10
    elif (current_market_status > -0.25): #less than 25%
        current_cash_required_equity = 0.05
    elif (current_market_status > -0.30): #less than 30%
        current_cash_required_equity = 0
```

This is how the algorithm works.

1. Starts with a 10,000 portfolio with 100% cash position on Jan 1, 2000. It can only choose to buy SPY.
2. Every single month, 1000 is deposited into portfolio.
3. For every single day, it keeps track of current market status

   1. Essentially the market status can be anything from 0% to -50%. 0% would means it's at an all time high, and any number between 0 and -50% is how much from the most recent all time high it has dropped.
4. For each day, it determines what cash position the portfolio should have based on the current market status. This could be any number between 50% and 0%.
5. Repeat this each day until Dec 31, 2019

So there is 50 options, and for each option there is 50 options.

The theory is, that if the market drops. We should keep less cash, since it is discounted. So if the market is going up each day, than we keep 30% on hand or something. If it drops 10%, we might want to keep 20% on hand. If it drops 50%, we might want to keep no cash on hand and shovel 100% of our deposits into the market.

The final result for best strategy is which one has the highest CAGR or Compound Annual Growth Rate.

I am just learning to code, very new to this. So it is very likely I totally messed this up and are doing the whole loop wrong for what I want. Any help with this is much appreciated.

I sorta set out to do this by using this loop to set the 14 metrics first, prior to running the whole script for the 20 years. So that each iteration of the 20 years has their own set of 7 possible market statuses, and how much cash should be held based on that.

```
status = np.arange(0, -0.50, -0.01)
req = np.arange(0.5, -0.01, -1)

    # for every fixed market status, go trough every single cash requirment. 
        # for every single market status, try every single cash req

for first in range(len(req)):
    first_req = round(req[first], 2) # this is the 1st element, rounded to 2 digit
    for second in range(first, len(req)):
        second_req = round(req[second], 2) # same with 2nd element
        for third in range(second, len(req)):
            third_req = round(req[third], 2)
            for fourth in range(third, len(req)):
                fourth_req = round(req[fourth], 2)
                for fifth in range(fourth, len(req)):
                    fifth_req = round(req[fifth], 2)
                    for sixth in range(fifth, len(req)):
                        sixth_req = round(req[fifth], 2)
                        for seventh in range(sixth, len(req)):
                            seventh_req = round(req[sixth], 2)
                            for first in range(len(status)):
                                first_status = round(status[first], 2) 
                                for second in range(first, len(status)):
                                    second_status = round(status[second], 2) 
                                    for third in range(second, len(status)):
                                        third_status = round(status[third], 2)
                                        for fourth in range(third, len(status)):
                                            fourth_status = round(status[fourth], 2)
                                            for fifth in range(fourth, len(status)):
                                                fifth_status = round(status[fifth], 2)
                                                for sixth in range(fifth, len(status)):
                                                    sixth_status = round(status[fifth], 2)
                                                    for seventh in range(sixth, len(status)):
                                                        seventh_status = round(status[sixth], 2)



                                                        print('')
                                                        print(first_req, second_req, third_req, fourth_req, fifth_req, sixth_req, seventh_req,) # you can replace this with your function
                                                        print(first_status, second_status, third_status, fourth_status, fifth_status, sixth_status, seventh_status,)
```

Comment: Have you considered a recursive approach to this?

Comment: I have only been coding and learning python for 6 weeksish, so I am a super noob haha. I am going to watch some vides on what recursive in python is on youtube :) Thanks for the suggestion! I really don't want to spend days running this current approach haha

Comment: check [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations)

Comment: @windstorm Just watched this video on recursion, and I think t would cause me to run out of memory as he explained it here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wMNrSM5RFMc

Comment: @woblob thanks for link, will check it out :)

Comment: *Uncontrolled* recursion will run out of memory, but if you take care to only recurse a limited number of times (like 20, if you need to recurse for each year or each metric, or a few hundred, for each month, or even a few thousand, for each day) you should be fine.